# In-house chat Ad broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I've noticed for the past few days that the *Visit House* advertisement on the right doesn't properly show the *most* active rooms. Is this just me or is there a problem in showing the correct rooms?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This has been posted on [WebApps meta](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/720/chat-activity-ad-displays-incorrect-activity).  Having these posted on multiple metas is part of why I posted [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67637/add-a-migration-path-from-per-site-meta-sites-to-mso-to-avoid-dupes-across-sites)

Comment: @rchen this appears to be fixed on our site

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been repaired overnight as the chat ad properly populates the rooms.

Comment: it was a bug in the chat API